# javascript is included and compile into application.js in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

I import my own `javascript` in my `application.js` like this:

```
//= require 'overlay'
```

then I include application in my `application.html.erb` like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

then I find that in my page I got

```
<script src="/assets/overlay-4f9aec59c40642be0f9be34f4dac3fdf.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application-7eb3406005b56099419de90c3e6ea11b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

in `/assets/application-7eb3406005b56099419de90c3e6ea11b.js?body=1` also iclude the `overlay.js` which means `overlay.js` is included in my page for twice.

such as I write this in `overlay.js`:

```
$('#ele').click(function() {console.log 'overlay.js';})
```

when I click the button, I will get two line `overlay.js`, how can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post the code to your page ?

Comment: what code do you need?

Comment: The page where you're seeing overlay.js being included in script tag.

Comment: I just add a button `ele` in the page for test

Comment: rails asset pipelining will never include a file twice however it'll give you a warning in your console, if there is no such warning then overlay.js is being included the second time by javascript_include_tag or script tag.

Comment: @ashish I don't think so, for example, I write `//= require 'bootstrap'`, so I have `<script src="/assets/bootstrap-f069863cd7c15927c7faef4bba9fc907.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>` in my page, but I find that `application.js` also includes `bootstrap.js`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70948/discussion-between-ashish-and-roger).

Answer (score 0):

Put your js file under the folder assets/javascripts 
Doing this you don't need to write this 
`//= require 'overlay'`  Instead of this write 
`//= require_tree .`    in your application.js file. Hope it will work.

Comment: I do not think this is a good idea, because `require_tree` will include all javascript file into my page, but some javascript for example `modernizr.js` I  do not want include them. so I need to include for myself.

Comment: @roger  You can include <%= javascript_include_tag "overlay.js", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %> directly into into your view file. put overlay.js under assets/javascripts folder. This way you don't need to do this: //= require 'overlay'  Hope it works.